# Are there any Unitarian Catholic Churches?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, unitarianism

### Preface to Question:

Weird question, I know that Catholicism's orthodox teachings are trinity, so this question is strange to me also.

Growing up, I was not raised catholic and believed that Jesus was God and still hold that clear teaching of scripture, but I remember arguing with a child in Jr. High who was catholic and said, "Jesus is not God, he is God's son," and denying that Jesus should receive any worship.

At first sound, this sounds like a kid that was misunderstanding the trinity. But growing up I was always told that Catholics in the area didn't believe Jesus was God.

Catholicism in general agrees on the same dogmas, but every now and then, many do disagree on small issues. Is this a wide spread thing?

Comment: What region of the world did you grow up in? It's fine if you would prefer to leave out that detail, but it would also make it much easier to research.

Comment: There is a big difference between calling onesself Catholic and actually being Catholic.  There are many off shoots of Catholicism that want to hold on to what they know to be the original Church founded by Christ, yet, the need to embrace modernism (Women Priests for example or Pre Vat separatists) These sects, although may have good intentions, have issues with obedience, and this counters the meaning behind the word Catholic which is;  "According to the Whole".  To hold Unitarian beliefs, is not to be Catholic.

Comment: If you're between the ages of 0 and 65 there's an good chance the Catholic kids you were arguing with was poorly taught. Find him, send him here!

Comment: @4castle Central Louisiana.

Comment: @PeterTurner Indeed, lol. Unfortunately he is died in a car accident 4 or 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but they are a modern phenomenon, and they go by the named of Arian rather than Unitarian.   They also are small groups, largely based on the Internet.

> Arian Catholicism is an Internet Church, founded in 2006, claiming to teach true Christianity. The church is Arian in nature but not Anomoean and follows the teachings of Arius of Alexandria - that Jesus was a man to be followed, not worshipped, who was the spiritual Son of God. God the Father and the Son of God were not co-eternal, nor of the same substance. Arian Catholics believe that Christianity was hijacked during the fourth century; that the Romans integrated Christianity with Paganism and the Roman State; the Romans introduced Trinitarianism, altering the ecumenism of the church; and that the Romans destroyed scriptures that were not in keeping with the newly authorised beliefs.
>
> According to their website, the official symbol of the Arian Catholic Church is the Chi-Rho cross, in preference to the crucifix or the other types of cross.
>
> Arian doctrine was historically deemed heresy by Trinitarian Christians, but the Arian Catholic Church likewise deem Trinitarian Christians to be heretics and apostates.

http://religion.wikia.com/wiki/Arian_Catholicism

**Note -  This group has either changed a lot, or another group has taken over with that name!  A few days ago I ran across an Arian Catholic Church but it was "non-dogmatic" advertised itself as far as "inclusivity" (Women in ministry, gay friendly etc.).   I however have had trouble finding that web site again (may be off line now).**

https://www.facebook.com/arian.catholic.church/?tn-str=k*F

There is a smilar "Orthodox" Arian group here.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRM2ela4Hr612CjTvIJCUbw

I seem to recall seeing other groups using the words "Essene" and "Nazarene" (which can mean a number of other things including New Age and Messianic Jewish/Hebrew Roots), but haven't seen anymore recently.